# How to JSON dump multiple dictionaries to disk without combining them in a list?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I am collecting tweets using the Twitter Python library. I can not afford to first combine all the dictionaries in a list and then dump it to file because of memory concerns. Hence I want to persist dictionaries to disk every few iterations, say after collecting every 1000 dictionaries. Is there a way to go about this?

If I dump the dictionaries directly without first putting them in a list, I get the following error while retrieving the json from file:

```
File "read_json.py", line 6, in <module>
jline = json.loads(line,"utf-8")
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 351, in loads
return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 454154 - line 1 column 4100740 (char 454153 - 4100739)
```

After going through questions on Stackoverflow that address these errors, I understood that one should combine the dictionaries in a list-like object and then dump - something which I can't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output the list manually without constructing it in python, write out a '[' then stream out the dicts (separated by a ','), when you want to close the file, write out a ']'. Then you should be able to load it again, e,g.:

```
>>> from json import loads, dumps
>>> a = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> b = {'c':3, 'd':4}
>>> loads("[{},{}]".format(dumps(a), dumps(b)))
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4}]
```

Comment: Taking the cue from you, I did it in a slightly different way:

    `fout = open(filename, "a")
    fout.write("[")
    tweets = getTweetsFromAPI()
    maxId = getMaxId(tweets)
    json.dump(tweets,fout)
    while 1:
        tweets = getTweetsFromAPI(max_id=maxId)
        fout.write(",")
        json.dump(tweets,fout)
    fout.write("]")
    fout.close()`

Thanks a ton!